# Install llvm-toolset-10.0 or newer in Centos7

Tags: c++, centos, clang, llvm, centos7

I used docker image `docker run -ti centos:7 /bin/bash`, i try install llvm-toolset-10.0
like this `yum install llvm-toolset-10.0` but got error `No package llvm-toolset-10.0 available.`

After that i tried use pre-built binraries from https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases, but got `bash: ./clang: cannot execute binary file`, i used `clang+llvm-13.0.0-powerpc64le-linux-rhel-7.9`.

Question how to install clang or llvm with version 10 or higher in Centos7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a llvm-toolset-10 build out on the [centos buildlogs](https://buildlogs.centos.org/c7-llvm-toolset-11.0.x86_64/). The rpms are unsigned since they never got published out to the official centos scl repos; thus they won't be trusted by default. Also note that since some of the packages in llvm-toolset have a dependency on devtoolset you will need to ensure you have the right devtoolset repo installed as well.

#### Add repo for devtoolset

```bash
sudo yum install centos-release-scl-rh
```

#### Create a custom repo pointing to buildlogs

```bash
sudo bash -c 'cat << EOF > /etc/yum.repos.d/llvmtoolset-build.repo
[llvmtoolset-build]
name=LLVM Toolset 11.0 - Build
baseurl=https://buildlogs.centos.org/c7-llvm-toolset-11.0.x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
EOF'
```

#### Install the llvm toolset packages you need

```bash
sudo yum install --nogpgcheck llvm-toolset-11.0-clang-tools-extra llvm-toolset-11.0-clang
```

#### Enable the llvm toolset

```bash
echo "source /opt/rh/llvm-toolset-11.0/enable" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

To determine why the llvm-toolset-10 rpms are not in the official SCLo repos, I put in [an issue into the centos issue tracker](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=18599).

Answer (score 0):

Install by conda or homebrew in general, you installation failure might be `powerpc64le` is not your processor’s type, it's an old processor type.